# issues related find_by_sql in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am using Rails 4 and I need to use find_by_sql in my active record model.Now I am facing two serious problems. First one is that it does not give me a particluar data whether it is giving #Employee:0x0000000b2a1718 as result. My model name is Employee and tbale name is employees. I am using pg.

Please tell me is there any solution.

Second problem is that how can I write any rails variable with in the sql query used in find_by_sql. For example I want to execute find_by_sql("select firstname from employee where id=@var"), where @var is a ruby variable.

The actual query I need to execute is select firstname from employee where comapact_string like %@var% using find_by_sql.

Comment: The first question I have is *why* you need to drop down to raw SQL when the example you give is not something that requires it.

Comment: No,,this is just an example query. The actual query I need to execute is select firstname from employee where firstname like %@var%.....dont know how to achieve this.

Comment: That's still easily accommodated by ActiveRecord.

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: you can use it like this, Employee.where("id LIKE '%?%'", @var).select(:firstname)

Comment: if I store it into a variable like @kol=Employee.where("compact_string LIKE '%?%'", @var).select(:firstname),,,,then I am unable to print it in terminal using puts

Comment: it is showing the error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in EmployeesController#new

Comment: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "snubpully500mm" LINE 1: ...e" FROM "employees" WHERE (compact_string LIKE '%'snubpully5... ^ : SELECT "employees"."firstname" FROM "employees" WHERE (compact_string LIKE '%'snubpully500mm'%')

Comment: @power That's not the right syntax. You need only `?` in the query or it messes up the escaping.

Comment: I am getting the same error in irb . Dont know how to manage it.

Comment: @tadman...r u sure that like is supported in postgres.

Answer (score 3):

There's degrees of customization when making a query. The simplest form is where you can use the built-in finders:

```
Employee.where(id: @var).pluck(:first name)
```

That will do a direct match, and if one's found, give you the `first_name` column value. No model is produced with `pluck`.

If you want to do an approximate match with `LIKE` you write out the `WHERE` clause more formally:

```
Employee.where('id LIKE ?', "%{@var}%").pluck(:first_name)
```

It's rare you need to write out an entire query with `find_by_sql`, but if you do you must be extremely cautious about what data you put in the query. It's strongly recommended to use placeholder values whenever possible, and if you absolutely must bypass this, *escape everything* no matter the source.

Comment: After using this in my code I am getting no result. And when I see the server terminal then I find that Employee.where('compact_string LIKE ?', "%{@var}%").pluck(:first_name).,,And it is showing no result,probably beacuse @var value is not replaced by the actual one during execution of query.

Comment: What is `@var`? Are you sure it's set correctly? Don't forget that instance variables are sensitive to the context in which they're created, so a controller variable won't work in model code. Have a look at your query log to see what's being executed: `log/development.log`

Comment: yeah,,I have initiated it with a string. It contains "snubpully500mm"

Comment: how to print all the fetched record in terminal. I mean can I store in a variable?

Comment: I want to use puts

Comment: Just use `rails c` for the console whenever you want to try things.